# Validation Failed (Laracasts Validation)

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate a registration form using [this](https://laracasts.com/lessons/from-install-to-registration-part-2) tutorial. However, upon submitting I get the following error message :

```
Laracasts \ Validation \ FormValidationException
Validation failed
```

Note that I am yet to disable my frontend validation for testing, and hence the values are automatically validated. Yet it still fails. This is my relevant code :

```
# RegistrationForm.php

<?php namespace forms;

# app/validators.php

use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidator;

class RegistrationForm extends FormValidator{

    protected $rules =[
            'first_name' => 'required|alpha|max:25',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha|max:25',
            'username' => 'required|unique:k_users|max:45',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
            'email' => 'required|unique:k_users|email',
            'Gender' => 'required|in:m,f,o',
            'year' => 'required|integer|min:1900|max:2014',
            'country' => 'required',
            'location' => 'max:50|alpha_spaces',
    ];
}
```

Storage function in RegisterController

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('first_name','last_name', 'username','password','email','Gender','year','country','location');
    try
    {
        $this->registrationForm->validate($input);
        Register::saveFormData();
        return Redirect::to('hello');
    }
    catch (FormValidationException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getErrors());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that your exception is not being catched:

```
catch (FormValidationException $e)
```

Is because you may be using a namespace, so you have two options:

1) Add the full namespace to your exception name

```
catch (\Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException $e)
```

2) Use it at the top of your file

```
use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException;
```

And you can keep it the way it is:

```
catch (FormValidationException $e)
```

Comment: Yup this solved my problem, thanks! I'm still trying to fully understand namespaces so this confused me greatly.

Comment: It's simple. When your .php file starts with a namespace command, PHP assumes everything inside it belongs to that namespace, if it doesn't you have to inform PHP by one of those two options.